# Easy way to pass node reference via post data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of input objects in my DOM, each with a button. When the user clicks one of the buttons, a dialog box is AJAXed. I would like to pass a reference to one of the input objects, depending on which button is clicked, to the dialog box. This way when the dialog box "Okay" button is clicked, it knows which input to manipulate on the original page.

Have I lost you yet? So how can I pass this input node reference to the AJAXed dialog box?

I am trying to steer away from using a global variable to store the node reference. I also do not want to have to give each input a unique id or name as this would force other areas of my code to become more complicated.

I suspect I will end up having to use one of the above solutions, but before I do, is there some way to pass a node reference via an URL without using the node's id or name? Would I have to use a selector index or something?

Note: Using JQuery.

Comment: Just with respect to your title: You cannot pass something like a reference to a node via POST or GET.

Comment: @Felix Kling ehh thanks for reading the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion IDs would be the most secure way of identifying nodes.

If you don't like this approach then all is left is using structure to identify elements. A generated path string containing parent hierarchy and child element position would probably do the trick. [This question about identifying DOM nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071295/what-is-the-best-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-dom-node) also contains some tips. The consensus there is to use XPath or something alike. This of course will only work if the structure of your page doesn't change too much.

Personally, I like IDs :)