# How to find the XPath of Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to know if it's possible to get the XPATH of the web element?

```
test = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.menu-listes ul.menu.menu-horizontal.menu_left li h3')

for t in test:
    //i want to have the XPATH
```

i tried `t.location` but i get just `{'y': 0, 'x': 0}`

Comment: Why don't you just find the xpath itself instead of using css selector?

Comment: it's just an example, i want to if it's POSSIBLE to get xpath of the web element or not

Comment: you should rather put html tag here? are you trying to find xpath from a css locator?

Comment: @RemcoW thanks, i searched before posting but i didn't see that question, however the answer is in JAVA, i need it in Python

Comment: @abhijeetkanade No, i try to find xpath from web element

Comment: @abhijeetkanade In Python it's pretty much the same. I've made an answer that literally translates the answer from the duplicate to python and implemented it in your code block. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176560/webdriver-get-elements-xpath) in Python (untested):

```
test = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.menu-listes ul.menu.menu-horizontal.menu_left li h3')

for t in test:
    driver.execute_script("""gPt=function(c){
                                 if(c.id!==''){
                                     return'id("'+c.id+'")'
                                 } 
                                 if(c===document.body){
                                     return c.tagName
                                 }
                                 var a=0;
                                 var e=c.parentNode.childNodes;
                                 for(var b=0;b<e.length;b++){
                                     var d=e[b];
                                     if(d===c){
                                         return gPt(c.parentNode)+'/'+c.tagName+'['+(a+1)+']'
                                     }
                                     if(d.nodeType===1&&d.tagName===c.tagName){
                                         a++
                                     }
                                 }
                             };
                             return gPt(arguments[0]).toLowerCase();""", t)
```

Comment: this code might be easier to write if you used one triple-quoted string rather than a bunch of quoted strings.

Comment: @BryanOakley Fair point, I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. xpath's aren't unique and if it did automatically get it, it probably won't be that efficient and robust of an xpath (for example, inspect element and check out the xpaths that Google Chrome gives you. They're usually something like div[1]/div[2]/div/div .. etc)

If you don't care about the fact that you might have a bad xpath you can write a function that keeps on getting parent until you reach the root all while keeping track of the path to the element you selected.