# Get XPATHs of all elements of an HTML/DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

Preferably in Javascript. 
[Maybe] iterate through all the nodes and `console.log()` its `XPath`.

I searched enough and could not find an answer.

**Why I need it?**

I want to see the c`oordinates(getBoundingClientRect())` of all leaf nodes of a DOM (means, elements of an HTML).

Comment: @ The one did a downvote, make a constructive comment - provide a link or any resource, suggestion.

Comment: The XPath for *all elements of an HTML DOM* is `//*`. You can use it for iteration through list of all nodes...

Comment: @Andersson, please write those iteration lines to print each XPath.

Comment: It won't *print XPath*, but will *return each webElement* that you can handle appropriately.

Comment: @Andersson, Please tell me more... how can I use the web elements returned to get coordinates with getBoundingClientRect(). Assume all of them don't have an ID.

Comment: In Python Selenium I would do something like `for node in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*'): print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();', node))`. I'm not sure how to implement the same for your tool in pure JavaScript

Comment: Thanks @Andersson. Could someone do it in Javascript?!

Comment: Code writing requests are generally considered as being too broad.

Comment: @VishalGupta was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of [How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256372/8291949) and [how do I get the XPath of an element in an X/HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9198430/8291949)

should do:

```js
function getXPath(node) {
    var comp, comps = [];
    var parent = null;
    var xpath = '';
    var getPos = function(node) {
        var position = 1, curNode;
        if (node.nodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
            return null;
        }
        for (curNode = node.previousSibling; curNode; curNode = curNode.previousSibling) {
            if (curNode.nodeName == node.nodeName) {
                ++position;
            }
        }
        return position;
     }

    if (node instanceof Document) {
        return '/';
    }

    for (; node && !(node instanceof Document); node = node.nodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE ? node.ownerElement : node.parentNode) {
        comp = comps[comps.length] = {};
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                comp.name = 'text()';
                break;
            case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
                comp.name = '@' + node.nodeName;
                break;
            case Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:
                comp.name = 'processing-instruction()';
                break;
            case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
                comp.name = 'comment()';
                break;
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                comp.name = node.nodeName;
                break;
        }
        comp.position = getPos(node);
    }

    for (var i = comps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        comp = comps[i];
        xpath += '/' + comp.name;
        if (comp.position != null) {
            xpath += '[' + comp.position + ']';
        }
    }

    return xpath;

}

var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    console.log(getXPath(all[i]));
}
```

The updated version works much better than the first installment.