# jQuery full support xpath plugin (generatation of xpath and selection by given xpath)

Tags: jquery, html, dom, xpath, jquery-plugins

I need xpath plugin for jquery which works in all browser and supports all xpath selectors (Since jquery supports basic xpath). Can stackoverflow members suggest one? Plugin should provide generation of xpath for given element and element selection for given xpath. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/xpath/)?

It has its own engine so it should work in all browsers(with javascript support)

Comment: Nice small plugin. However i guess it does not support xpath generation by given element. Am i right?

Comment: @antindexer, yes it doesnt support, but you can write write such feature yourself or search for existing solutions(for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631931/449553)

Comment: Yes I can do it. I can even write xpath selector by given xpath by myself. However I ask ready made solution. If there is no other. I will do so for sure. Thank you.