# javascript [No Jquery] Check if an element is inside a div or not

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if the element is not directly inside a `div`.

For example Consider the follwing markup-

If I place a `div` inside another `div`.

Then I could use this code-

```
if(document.getElementById('innerDiv').parentElement.id == 'outerDiv') )
```

where innerdiv is inside the outerdiv.

But what if I place four `div's` inside one another then how can i check that any div is inside the given div.

there may be a better option than using this code

```
innerelem.parentnode.parentnode.parentnode.parentnode
```

I hope i was able to explain what i want to do????

Comment: maybe get the inner html of the container div, and regex test it for occurances of `id='innerDiv'`?

Comment: If you use the 1 option you have mentioned, it doesn't matter how many `div`s there are, it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there may be a better option than using this code

A couple of options:

1. If you really have `id`s (or anything else you can use to uniquely identify the inner element inside the outer one), then you can use `querySelector`:

   ```
   if (document.getElementById("outerDiv").querySelector("#innerDiv")) {
       // Yes, it's inside it
   } else {
       // No, it isn't
   }
   ```

   `querySelector` returns `null` if it doesn't find the element, and when you use it on an element, it only looks inside that element's descendants (not through the overall document). `querySelector` is supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.
2. If you need more flexibility, a loop would be less brittle than `.parentNode.parentNode...`:

   ```
   var node, inside;
   inside = false;
   for (node = innerelem; node; node = node.parentNode) {
       if (node.id === 'outerDiv') {
           inside = true;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Node.contains` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains:

`if(document.getElementById('outerDiv').contains(document.getElementById('innerDiv')))`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function like this:

```
function findUpId(innerId, outerId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(innerId);
    while (el.parentNode) {
        el = el.parentNode;
        if (el.id === outerId)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then call:

```
var inside = findUpId("innerDiv","outerDiv");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="oInput">
    <input id="1" type="text">
    <input id="2" type="text">
    <input id="3" type="text">
    <input id="4" type="text">
    <input id="5" type="text">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oInput = document.getElementById('oInput'), oChild;
    for(i = 0; i < oInput.childNodes.length; i++){
        oChild = oInput.childNodes[i];
        if(oChild.id== 'your id'){
            alert('it is child');
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631931/3940047 and find the method getPathTo(element)

You can execute that to get the xpath of the element you're referring to. You can check in the xpath if your element is inside a given div id.