# Using JavaScript and/or JQuery, how can I find the "XPath" or map to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xpath, prototypejs

```
//Example:
var elem = document.querySelector('unique_id');
//assuming no ID or unique characteric:

functionName(elem); //or $.functionName
//name or create this function

//returns:
//  "document.divNameOrId.divNameIfNoId.testParagraph.spanElem" 
//    or
//  something like: document[0][1][5][3]
```

Please, Name `functionName()` or `$.functionName` or Define `functionName()` or `$.functionName`.

PrototypeJS answers are not preferred but they are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be answered before but a recursive method would do the trick.  See the [getPathTo(element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631820/im-storing-click-coordinates-in-my-db-and-then-reloading-them-later-and-showing/2631931#2631931) method of this answer to a different question.