# Xpath of element on another website/cross domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, xpath, cross-domain

I want to get the `XPATH` of an element on a website (my own domain), which I got it using `JavaScript` code as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631820/im-storing-click-coordinates-in-my-db-and-then-reloading-them-later-and-showing#answer-2631931) answer.

Now what I want to click on button which will open a url (cross domain) window and when user click on an element on that window it's `XPATH` is captured.

I tried doing the same using `iframe` with no luck.

Now my question is there a way to get the `XPATH` of an element of **`another website`**/ **`Cross domain`**?

Comment: I assume you want to do this processing on the client side, not from a server. How about getting the page via a `GET` ajax request, then working on the result?
Not sure if I understood your question correctly. Which part of the task is problematic for you?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Getting the page via `GET` will give me the `html` but  it will loose the user experience of selecting the element from a page, I updated the question too.

Comment: Can the other domain cooperate? That way you could exchange data using `postMessage` https://w3c.github.io/webmessaging/#dom-window-postmessage between different domains. Otherwise I don't think there is a way with normal client-side script, unless you write a browser extension or plugin.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : Yes, other domain is corporate.

Comment: I did not ask whether the other domain is a corporate site, rather whether it can cooperate, meaning whether they can set up script on their site to use the `postMessage` method to exchange data with your site.

Comment: No, they can not set up the `script`, actually I want to write some solution which will be generic to all websites. E.g. `stackoverflow` might be the one out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I've gathered that you want to capture information from another website that doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers that include your domain (e.g. the other site does not have [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) enabled). This is not possible to do cross-domain and client-side due to the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) implemented in most modern browsers. The Same-Origin Policy prevents any resources on your site from interacting with resources on any other site (unless the other site explicitly shares them with your site using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header).

If you want to get information about another site from your site, there is no way around using server-side code. A simple solution would be to implement a server-side proxy that re-serves off-site pages from your own origin, so the Same-Origin Policy will not be violated.

Comment: That's correct, but getting the html on server side will not work for me as I want user to select elements from web page to get the `XPATH` of the same.

Comment: @Arpit To the best of my knowledge this is not possible without any server-side code, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is not possible without cooperation from the other (x-domain) site. Browsers are designed not to allow access to the DOM of x-domain documents (`iframe` included) for security reasons.

If you had cooperation from the other site, they could load your javascript file and then use [postmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass the xpath to the original page.

Other options would be to create a bookmarklet users could use on the other page, or a browser extension (Chrome and FF are pretty easy to develop for)... depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the data using jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, and append it to your page.

From there, the DOM nodes from your external page should be accessible for your processing.

```
$('#where-you-want').load('//example.com body', function() {
    console.log($('#where-you-want'))

    // process the DOM node under `#where-you-want` here with XPath.
})
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/xsvkdugo/

P.S.: this assumes you are working with a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)-enabled site.

Comment: This will not work in my case as it will loose the user experience of selecting the elements from the website.

Comment: @Arpit no problem, then append to your page instead of a document fragment. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This will definitely result in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: what do you mean? you must enable CORS do to this.