# Get XPath of a DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xpath

**I need to get the XPath of a DOM element to persist it so I can look for that element lather.**

I've tried the `getPathTo` method of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631820/im-storing-click-coordinates-in-my-db-and-then-reloading-them-later-and-showing/2631931#2631931) but when I call the method with a jQuery-created object like this...

```
getPathTo(jQuery('h3').first());
```

...I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined(…)

I've tried to replace `parentNode` with `parent()`, `childNodes` with `children()`, and `tagName` with `prop('tagName')`, but then I received *undefined* as the function result...

**So, do you have a similar function to `getPathTo` that works with jQuery?**

Comment: Why not just store a reference to that element in a variable within scope of all the required functions?

Comment: `getPathTo(jQuery('h3').first()[0])`

Comment: I Think your Problem is that you use a documentElement in jQuery Context. You can try to extract the element to javascript native level. Like this:
 var element = jQuery('h3');
 element.childNodes....

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan because I need the element to be retrieved in another session.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, it works. Maybe you want to post it like an answer.

Comment: @FranCavs90 then why not just call `$('h3:first')` in that session?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That was just an example. I need to save multiple DOM elements so I can replace them with others lather (and this replacement depends of other unrelated events).

Comment: Ok fair enough. Though my point remains; I'm sure there's a better way to do this than using XPath.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, there is. I'm working on an algorithm that will try to find the element in multiple ways, XPath is just one of them. Another point is that I have no control over the DOM elements - maybe they can change over the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method expects a DOM node and you are giving it a jQuery object

```
getPathTo(jQuery('h3').first()[0])
```

or

```
getPathTo(jQuery('h3').first().get(0))
```