# How to get xPath from html page (WebView)

Tags: java, android, xpath

How to determine the XPATH of an element at html page, opened in CrossWalkView(WebView)  by onTouch event?

Answer (score -1):

Problem was solved by using JS.
JS solution i got here: 
[I'm storing click coordinates in my db and then reloading them later and showing them on the site where the click happened, how do I make sure it loads in the same place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631820/im-storing-click-coordinates-in-my-db-and-then-reloading-them-later-and-showing/2631931#2631931)

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.get_xpath);
                Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
                String javascript = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
                myWebView.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null);
```

and here`s my JS code:

```
document.onclick= function(event) {
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event;                     // IE hack
    var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement; // another IE hack

    var root= document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'? document.documentElement : document.body;
    var mxy= [event.clientX+root.scrollLeft, event.clientY+root.scrollTop];

    var path= getPathTo(target);
    var txy= getPageXY(target);
    alert('Clicked element '+path+' offset '+(mxy[0]-txy[0])+', '+(mxy[1]-txy[1]));
}

function getPathTo(element) {
    if (element.id!=='')
        return 'id("'+element.id+'")';
    if (element===document.body)
        return element.tagName;

    var ix= 0;
    var siblings= element.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i= 0; i<siblings.length; i++) {
        var sibling= siblings[i];
        if (sibling===element)
            return getPathTo(element.parentNode)+'/'+element.tagName+'['+(ix+1)+']';
        if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)
            ix++;
    }
}

function getPageXY(element) {
    var x= 0, y= 0;
    while (element) {
        x+= element.offsetLeft;
        y+= element.offsetTop;
        element= element.offsetParent;
    }
    return [x, y];
}
```