# How to convert from Path to XPath, given a browser event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

On a MouseEvent instance, we have a property called path, it might look like this:

[image]

Does anybody know if there is a reliable way to translate this path array into an XPath? I assume that this path data is the best data to start from? Is there a library I can use to do the conversion?

This library looks promising, but it doesn't use the path property of an event: https://github.com/johannhof/xpath-dom

Comment: Please add a sample of how the expected XML should look like.

Answer (score 6):

There's not a unique XPath to a node, so you'll have to decide what's the most appropriate way of constructing a path. Use IDs where available? Numeral position in the document? Position relative to other elements?

See getPathTo() in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631820/im-storing-click-coordinates-in-my-db-and-then-reloading-them-later-and-showing/2631931#2631931) for one possible approach.

PS: Taken from [Javascript get XPath of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node)

Another option is to use SelectorGadget from below link

https://dv0akt2986vzh.cloudfront.net/unstable/lib/selectorgadget.js

The actual code for the DOM path is at

https://dv0akt2986vzh.cloudfront.net/stable/lib/dom.js

Usage: on http://google.com

```
elem = document.getElementById("q")
predict = new DomPredictionHelper()
predict.pathOf(elem)
// gives "body.default-theme.des-mat:nth-child(2) div#_Alw:nth-child(4) form#f:nth-child(2) div#fkbx:nth-child(2) input#q:nth-child(2)"
predict.predictCss([elem],[])
// gives "#q"
```

CODE if link goes down

```
// Copyright (c) 2008, 2009 Andrew Cantino
// Copyright (c) 2008, 2009 Kyle Maxwell

function DomPredictionHelper() {};
DomPredictionHelper.prototype = new Object();

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.recursiveNodes = function(e){
  var n;
  if(e.nodeName && e.parentNode && e != document.body) {
    n = this.recursiveNodes(e.parentNode);
  } else {
    n = new Array();
  }
  n.push(e);
  return n;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.escapeCssNames = function(name) {
  if (name) {
    try {
      return name.replace(/\s*sg_\w+\s*/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
                  replace(/\./g, '\\.').replace(/#/g, '\\#').replace(/\>/g, '\\>').replace(/\,/g, '\\,').replace(/\:/g, '\\:');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('---');
      console.log("exception in escapeCssNames");
      console.log(name);
      console.log('---');
      return '';
    }
  } else {
    return '';
  }
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.childElemNumber = function(elem) {
  var count = 0;
  while (elem.previousSibling && (elem = elem.previousSibling)) {
    if (elem.nodeType == 1) count++;
  }
  return count;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.pathOf = function(elem){
  var nodes = this.recursiveNodes(elem);
  var self = this;
  var path = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var e = nodes[i];
    if (e) {
      path += e.nodeName.toLowerCase();
      var escaped = e.id && self.escapeCssNames(new String(e.id));
      if(escaped && escaped.length > 0) path += '#' + escaped;

      if(e.className) {
        jQuery.each(e.className.split(/ /), function() {
          var escaped = self.escapeCssNames(this);
          if (this && escaped.length > 0) {
            path += '.' + escaped;
          }
        });
      }
      path += ':nth-child(' + (self.childElemNumber(e) + 1) + ')';
      path += ' '
    }
  }
  if (path.charAt(path.length - 1) == ' ') path = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
  return path;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.commonCss = function(array) {
  try {
    var dmp = new diff_match_patch();
  } catch(e) {
    throw "Please include the diff_match_patch library.";
  }

  if (typeof array == 'undefined' || array.length == 0) return '';

  var existing_tokens = {};
  var encoded_css_array = this.encodeCssForDiff(array, existing_tokens);

  var collective_common = encoded_css_array.pop();
  jQuery.each(encoded_css_array, function(e) {
    var diff = dmp.diff_main(collective_common, this);
    collective_common = '';
    jQuery.each(diff, function() {
      if (this[0] == 0) collective_common += this[1];
    });
  });
  return this.decodeCss(collective_common, existing_tokens);
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.tokenizeCss = function(css_string) {
  var skip = false;
  var word = '';
  var tokens = [];

  var css_string = css_string.replace(/,/, ' , ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  var length = css_string.length;
  var c = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    c = css_string[i];

    if (skip) {
      skip = false;
    } else if (c == '\\') {
      skip = true;
    } else if (c == '.' || c == ' ' || c == '#' || c == '>' || c == ':' || c == ',') {
      if (word.length > 0) tokens.push(word);
      word = '';
    }
    word += c;
    if (c == ' ' || c == ',') {
      tokens.push(word);
      word = '';
    }
  }
  if (word.length > 0) tokens.push(word);
  return tokens;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.decodeCss = function(string, existing_tokens) {
  var inverted = this.invertObject(existing_tokens);
  var out = '';
  jQuery.each(string.split(''), function() {
    out += inverted[this];
  });
  return this.cleanCss(out);
};

// Encode css paths for diff using unicode codepoints to allow for a large number of tokens.
DomPredictionHelper.prototype.encodeCssForDiff = function(strings, existing_tokens) {
  var codepoint = 50;
  var self = this;
  var strings_out = [];
  jQuery.each(strings, function() {
    var out = new String();
    jQuery.each(self.tokenizeCss(this), function() {
      if (!existing_tokens[this]) {
        existing_tokens[this] = String.fromCharCode(codepoint++);
      }
      out += existing_tokens[this];
    });
    strings_out.push(out);
  });
  return strings_out;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.simplifyCss = function(css, selected_paths, rejected_paths) {
  var self = this;
  var parts = self.tokenizeCss(css);
  var best_so_far = "";
  if (self.selectorGets('all', selected_paths, css) && self.selectorGets('none', rejected_paths, css)) best_so_far = css;
  for (var pass = 0; pass < 4; pass++) {
    for (var part = 0; part < parts.length; part++) {
      var first = parts[part].substring(0,1);
      if (self.wouldLeaveFreeFloatingNthChild(parts, part)) continue;
      if ((pass == 0 && first == ':') || // :nth-child
          (pass == 1 && first != ':' && first != '.' && first != '#' && first != ' ') || // elem, etc.
          (pass == 2 && first == '.') || // classes
          (pass == 3 && first == '#')) // ids
      {
        var tmp = parts[part];
        parts[part] = '';
        var selector = self.cleanCss(parts.join(''));
        if (selector == '') {
          parts[part] = tmp;
          continue;
        }
        if (self.selectorGets('all', selected_paths, selector) && self.selectorGets('none', rejected_paths, selector)) {
          best_so_far = selector;
        } else {
          parts[part] = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return self.cleanCss(best_so_far);
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.wouldLeaveFreeFloatingNthChild = function(parts, part) {
  return (((part - 1 >= 0 && parts[part - 1].substring(0, 1) == ':') && 
           (part - 2 < 0 || parts[part - 2] == ' ') && 
           (part + 1 >= parts.length || parts[part + 1] == ' ')) || 
          ((part + 1 < parts.length && parts[part + 1].substring(0, 1) == ':') && 
           (part + 2 >= parts.length || parts[part + 2] == ' ') && 
           (part - 1 < 0 || parts[part - 1] == ' ')));
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.cleanCss = function(css) {
  return css.replace(/\>/, ' > ').replace(/,/, ' , ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').replace(/,$/, '');
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.getPathsFor = function(arr) {
  var self = this;
  var out = [];
  jQuery.each(arr, function() {
    if (this && this.nodeName) {
      out.push(self.pathOf(this));
    }
  })
  return out;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.predictCss = function(s, r) {
  var self = this;

  if (s.length == 0) return '';
  var selected_paths = self.getPathsFor(s);
  var rejected_paths = self.getPathsFor(r);

  var css = self.commonCss(selected_paths);
  var simplest = self.simplifyCss(css, selected_paths, rejected_paths);

  // Do we get off easy?
  if (simplest.length > 0) return simplest;

  // Okay, then make a union and possibly try to reduce subsets.
  var union = '';
  jQuery.each(s, function() {
    union = self.pathOf(this) + ", " + union;
  });
  union = self.cleanCss(union);

  return self.simplifyCss(union, selected_paths, rejected_paths);
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.fragmentSelector = function(selector) {
  var self = this;
  var out = [];
  jQuery.each(selector.split(/\,/), function() {
    var out2 = [];
    jQuery.each(self.cleanCss(this).split(/\s+/), function() {
      out2.push(self.tokenizeCss(this));
    });
    out.push(out2);
  });
  return out;
};

// Everything in the first selector must be present in the second.
DomPredictionHelper.prototype.selectorBlockMatchesSelectorBlock = function(selector_block1, selector_block2) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selector_block1.length; j++) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(selector_block1[j], selector_block2) == -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

// Assumes list is an array of complete CSS selectors represented as strings.
DomPredictionHelper.prototype.selectorGets = function(type, list, the_selector) {
  var self = this;
  var result = true;

  if (list.length == 0 && type == 'all') return false;
  if (list.length == 0 && type == 'none') return true;

  var selectors = self.fragmentSelector(the_selector);

  var cleaned_list = [];
  jQuery.each(list, function() {
    cleaned_list.push(self.fragmentSelector(this)[0]);
  });

  jQuery.each(selectors, function() {
    if (!result) return;
    var selector = this;
    jQuery.each(cleaned_list, function(pos) {
      if (!result || this == '') return;
      if (self._selectorGets(this, selector)) {
        if (type == 'none') result = false;
        cleaned_list[pos] = '';
      }
    });
  });

  if (type == 'all' && cleaned_list.join('').length > 0) { // Some candidates didn't get matched.
    result = false;
  }

  return result;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype._selectorGets = function(candidate_as_blocks, selector_as_blocks) {
  var cannot_match = false;
  var position = candidate_as_blocks.length - 1;
  for (var i = selector_as_blocks.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (cannot_match) break;
    if (i == selector_as_blocks.length - 1) { // First element on right.
      // If we don't match the first element, we cannot match.
      if (!this.selectorBlockMatchesSelectorBlock(selector_as_blocks[i], candidate_as_blocks[position])) cannot_match = true;
      position--;
    } else {
      var found = false;
      while (position > -1 && !found) {
        found = this.selectorBlockMatchesSelectorBlock(selector_as_blocks[i], candidate_as_blocks[position]);
        position--;
      }
      if (!found) cannot_match = true;
    }
  }
  return !cannot_match;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.invertObject = function(object) {
  var new_object = {};
  jQuery.each(object, function(key, value) {
    new_object[value] = key;
  });
  return new_object;
};

DomPredictionHelper.prototype.cssToXPath = function(css_string) {
  var tokens = this.tokenizeCss(css_string);
  if (tokens[0] && tokens[0] == ' ') tokens.splice(0, 1);
  if (tokens[tokens.length - 1] && tokens[tokens.length - 1] == ' ') tokens.splice(tokens.length - 1, 1);

  var css_block = [];
  var out = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (tokens[i] == ' ') {
      out += this.cssToXPathBlockHelper(css_block);
      css_block = [];
    } else {
      css_block.push(tokens[i]);
    }
  }

  return out + this.cssToXPathBlockHelper(css_block);
};

// Process a block (html entity, class(es), id, :nth-child()) of css
DomPredictionHelper.prototype.cssToXPathBlockHelper = function(css_block) {
  if (css_block.length == 0) return '//';
  var out = '//';
  var first = css_block[0].substring(0,1);

  if (first == ',') return " | ";

  if (jQuery.inArray(first, [':', '#', '.']) != -1) {
    out += '*';
  }

  var expressions = [];
  var re = null;

  for(var i = 0; i < css_block.length; i++) {
    var current = css_block[i];
    first = current.substring(0,1);
    var rest = current.substring(1);

    if (first == ':') {
      // We only support :nth-child(n) at the moment.
      if (re = rest.match(/^nth-child\((\d+)\)$/))
        expressions.push('(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = ' + re[1] + ') and parent::*)');
    } else if (first == '.') {
      expressions.push('contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "' + rest + '", " " ))');
    } else if (first == '#') {
      expressions.push('(@id = "' + rest + '")');
    } else if (first == ',') {
    } else {
      out += current;
    }
  }

  if (expressions.length > 0) out += '[';
  for (var i = 0; i < expressions.length; i++) {
    out += expressions[i];
    if (i < expressions.length - 1) out += ' and ';
  }
  if (expressions.length > 0) out += ']';
  return out;
};
```