How to form a querySelector from just a JavaScript HTML element reference
Ok, so I have this puppeteer project where I had done the research and was able to grab the ID tags from some username, password, and submit button elements on a login page and use them to target the elements to login. Now some changes has been requested where this needs to function on multiple different possible login pages that I may not know about.
One possible solution is when I have the user setup their parameters, and collect the URL of the login page they are wanting to use, I was going to open a new tab with Puppeteer to the page, and guide them through clicking on the username input, then the password input, then the submit button. When they do this, I can capture the click events, event.preventDefault() it, and then have an event.target reference to these input fields to validate the automation process.
If the input has an ID tag associated with it, that would be awesome and simple to store as a querySelector. If it has a class, I can test to see if only one element matches that class name or find the indexOf the input in the array of elements with that class.
What if it doesn't have a class or ID tag though? What other reliable ways could I form a querySelector or way of targeting the same elements repeatedly? Should I think about finding the index of this element in documeny.querySelectorAll("input")?
I was also thinking of recording the x & y axis of the click event and then replicating a click at that point, and then grabbing the event.target again that way, but if a banner or something on this website I know nothing about, pops up, it would shift the layout of the page and make this an unreliable way of doing this as well.
I am curious to hear what other ideas this community can come up with. Lots of smart people in here!

See: getPathTo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631820/how-do-i-ensure-saved-click-coordinates-can-be-reload-to-the-same-place-even-if/2631931#2631931

Maybe work out how you would identify these things yourself by looking at the page's HTML before trying to express that in a query.

@ScottHunter The idea of this post was to come up with the most reliable way to target an element repeatedly on a page we know nothing about. If I could research the page layout first then I wouldn’t need a programmatic solution. However this function that Brahma Dev is referring to looks very promising!

@BrahmaDev That looks very promising and exactly what I am looking for, however the question here I feel is not the same as the question there. Maybe post that solution here?

There is no silver bullet to find inputs on a page, and I can tell you to avoid ideas like indexes and x/y coordinates which will definitely fail. Every page has unique layout and behavior and has its own "best way" to choose selectors. See Convenient way to get input for puppeteer page.click(). I'd also describe what your project is at a higher level. You could try using a GPT to generate code, but this is super brittle too, so maybe some complex combination of strategies.

If you can't come up with an algorithm that you could use, how could you hope to code it in a query?

@ScottHunter In my opinion I would probably go with collecting all the inputs on the page and recording the index of the input I want and forming a query that way. If the page layout ever breaks with a revision, the new elements could be grabbed by repeating the configuration process as the service I've created is user configurable. However, I posted this question to get better ideas if one exists because that is what Stack Overflow is about. With an opinion such as yours, this site shouldn't exist.

Take a look at this https://github.com/antonmedv/finder

I have the feeling that you don't get how HTML forms work. From your description of the issue it sounds like something complicated, but in the end it is probably straight forward. Can you give an example of the input elements you write about. An maybe explain what you mean by "collect the URL of the login page they are wanting to use" -- should the user write a URL or is there a select element with options?

@chrwahl I understand how forms work. I was trying to describe the challenge in its simplistic form without involving the scope of the entire project which is multifaceted to say the least. Yes, the user is entering their own url with the initial setup of this device. I had it already working expecting a specific type of login page layout with known variables such as ID tags. This has now changed as they want the project to accept other web UIs that were not initially planned for. I can adapt what I have already but was interested in looking for login fields with little info about the page.
