# Javascript get XPath of a node

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

Is there anyway to return an XPath string of a DOM element in Javascript?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's not a unique XPath to a node, so you'll have to decide what's the most appropriate way of constructing a path. Use IDs where available? Numeral position in the document? Position relative to other elements?

See `getPathTo()` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631820/im-storing-click-coordinates-in-my-db-and-then-reloading-them-later-and-showing/2631931#2631931) for one possible approach.

Comment: Hey, thanks that looks like a nice function. I made another question more appropriate and more context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661918/javascript-crazy-idea-finding-a-node . In retrospect I should have edited this one... oops lol.

Comment: ＋１  “there’s not a unique XPath to a node” (and the feasible alternatives).

Comment: XPath is well defined as path to a node from root of the document.

Comment: I'm taking "there's not a unique XPath" to mean "there's many ways to skin this cat".

Answer (score 96):

I refactored this from another example. It will attempt to check or there is for sure a unique id and if so use that case to shorten the expression.

Please note if one of the nodes has siblings using the same `class` attribute value, the **XPath will not differentiate which sibling you are trying to select**.

```js
function createXPathFromElement(elm) { 
    var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
    for (var segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) 
    { 
        if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) { 
                var uniqueIdCount = 0; 
                for (var n=0;n < allNodes.length;n++) { 
                    if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute('id') && allNodes[n].id == elm.id) uniqueIdCount++; 
                    if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break; 
                }; 
                if ( uniqueIdCount == 1) { 
                    segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")'); 
                    return segs.join('/'); 
                } else { 
                    segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '"]'); 
                } 
        } else if (elm.hasAttribute('class')) { 
            segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]'); 
        } else { 
            for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) { 
                if (sib.localName == elm.localName)  i++; }; 
                segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']'); 
        }; 
    }; 
    return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null; 
}; 

function lookupElementByXPath(path) { 
    var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator(); 
    var result = evaluator.evaluate(path, document.documentElement, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
    return  result.singleNodeValue; 
}
```

Comment: Have tested the XPaths these produce using PHP's DOMDocument and DOMXPath objects – they seem to work really well.

Comment: This is great! I've looking for something like this for a while, and this is really the most complete solution I've seen. You got my +1. Thanks!

Comment: `segs` becomes a global variable here.

Comment: This doesn't work on [this page](http://www.icanvas.com/anderson-design-group-marthas-vineyard-maryland-blue-canvas-print-art.html?utm_source=google+utm_medium=cse+utm_campaign=GoogleProducts&gclid=CI2ghPf4isUCFYpgfgod6l8Ang), e.g.

1. In Chrome dev tools, click on an unselected DOM element for a price where the price is not the first listed price. Save that element into variable.
2. Run the algorithm on that element.
3. It brings you back to the first element in that pane only.

Comment: This is awesome !!

Comment: This is a great function! Is there something similar to this for getting the CSS selector of an element?

Comment: This is excellent work! btw, if your node is case sensitive, simply remove all `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: not entirely accurate since when two siblings have the same `class` attribute the first will always get picked up...

Comment: @AndreiRoba, I see the same problem. When there is siblings, only the first child's xpath get picked up. Have you found an alertnative?

Answer (score 26):

Here is a *functional programming* style ES6 function for the job:

```js
function getXPathForElement(element) {
    const idx = (sib, name) => sib 
        ? idx(sib.previousElementSibling, name||sib.localName) + (sib.localName == name)
        : 1;
    const segs = elm => !elm || elm.nodeType !== 1 
        ? ['']
        : elm.id && document.getElementById(elm.id) === elm
            ? [`id("${elm.id}")`]
            : [...segs(elm.parentNode), `${elm.localName.toLowerCase()}[${idx(elm)}]`];
    return segs(element).join('/');
}

function getElementByXPath(path) { 
    return (new XPathEvaluator()) 
        .evaluate(path, document.documentElement, null, 
                        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null) 
        .singleNodeValue; 
} 

// Demo:
const li = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(2)');
const path = getXPathForElement(li);
console.log(path);
console.log(li === getElementByXPath(path)); // true
```

```html
<div>
    <table id="start"></table>
    <div>
        <ul><li>option</ul></ul> 
        <span>title</span>
        <ul>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>select this</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will use an `id` selector, unless the element is not the first one with that id. Class selectors are not used, because in interactive web pages classes may change often.

Comment: instead of ```document.querySelector(`#${elm.id}`)``` just use `document.getElementById(elm.id)` because the former fails on Chrome when id contains only digits.

Comment: Just wanted to point to `Rohit Luthra's` modification of this anser to address SVG elements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55793129/3917091.

Comment: "Class selectors are not used, because in interactive web pages classes may change often" -- this also applies to XPaths in general. Here's an example I just copied in devtools: `id("mG61Hd")/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[12]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]` <-- this is not going to be a very reliable selector

Comment: @thdoan, true, but this question is about xpaths... ;-) And if we must choose *within* the context of xpaths, the bet on *structure* is more reliable than on *classes*.

Answer (score 21):

I've adapted the [algorithm Chromium uses](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/77578ccb4082ae20a9326d9e673225f1189ebb63/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/elements/DOMPath.js#L242) to calculate the XPath from devtools below.

To use this as-written you'd call `Elements.DOMPath.xPath(<some DOM node>, false)`. The last parameter controls whether you get the shorter "Copy XPath" (if `true`) or "Copy full XPath".

```js
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

Elements = {};
Elements.DOMPath = {};

/**
 * @param {!Node} node
 * @param {boolean=} optimized
 * @return {string}
 */
Elements.DOMPath.xPath = function (node, optimized) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
        return '/';
    }

    const steps = [];
    let contextNode = node;
    while (contextNode) {
        const step = Elements.DOMPath._xPathValue(contextNode, optimized);
        if (!step) {
            break;
        }  // Error - bail out early.
        steps.push(step);
        if (step.optimized) {
            break;
        }
        contextNode = contextNode.parentNode;
    }

    steps.reverse();
    return (steps.length && steps[0].optimized ? '' : '/') + steps.join('/');
};

/**
 * @param {!Node} node
 * @param {boolean=} optimized
 * @return {?Elements.DOMPath.Step}
 */
Elements.DOMPath._xPathValue = function (node, optimized) {
    let ownValue;
    const ownIndex = Elements.DOMPath._xPathIndex(node);
    if (ownIndex === -1) {
        return null;
    }  // Error.

    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            if (optimized && node.getAttribute('id')) {
                return new Elements.DOMPath.Step('//*[@id="' + node.getAttribute('id') + '"]', true);
            }
            ownValue = node.localName;
            break;
        case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
            ownValue = '@' + node.nodeName;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            ownValue = 'text()';
            break;
        case Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:
            ownValue = 'processing-instruction()';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            ownValue = 'comment()';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
            ownValue = '';
            break;
        default:
            ownValue = '';
            break;
    }

    if (ownIndex > 0) {
        ownValue += '[' + ownIndex + ']';
    }

    return new Elements.DOMPath.Step(ownValue, node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE);
};

/**
 * @param {!Node} node
 * @return {number}
 */
Elements.DOMPath._xPathIndex = function (node) {
    // Returns -1 in case of error, 0 if no siblings matching the same expression,
    // <XPath index among the same expression-matching sibling nodes> otherwise.
    function areNodesSimilar(left, right) {
        if (left === right) {
            return true;
        }

        if (left.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && right.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return left.localName === right.localName;
        }

        if (left.nodeType === right.nodeType) {
            return true;
        }

        // XPath treats CDATA as text nodes.
        const leftType = left.nodeType === Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE ? Node.TEXT_NODE : left.nodeType;
        const rightType = right.nodeType === Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE ? Node.TEXT_NODE : right.nodeType;
        return leftType === rightType;
    }

    const siblings = node.parentNode ? node.parentNode.children : null;
    if (!siblings) {
        return 0;
    }  // Root node - no siblings.
    let hasSameNamedElements;
    for (let i = 0; i < siblings.length; ++i) {
        if (areNodesSimilar(node, siblings[i]) && siblings[i] !== node) {
            hasSameNamedElements = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasSameNamedElements) {
        return 0;
    }
    let ownIndex = 1;  // XPath indices start with 1.
    for (let i = 0; i < siblings.length; ++i) {
        if (areNodesSimilar(node, siblings[i])) {
            if (siblings[i] === node) {
                return ownIndex;
            }
            ++ownIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;  // An error occurred: |node| not found in parent's children.
};

/**
 * @unrestricted
 */
Elements.DOMPath.Step = class {
    /**
     * @param {string} value
     * @param {boolean} optimized
     */
    constructor(value, optimized) {
        this.value = value;
        this.optimized = optimized || false;
    }

    /**
     * @override
     * @return {string}
     */
    toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
};
```

Update 2022-08-14: [Here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/panels/elements/DOMPath.ts?q=case:yes%20file:DOMPath.%5Btj%5Ds&ss=chromium) is a TypeScript version.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work anymore and I think they maybe updated the source code, because I downloaded the latest version and couldn't find any trace of this code. 
However, the code you provided does it's job very well! 
And could you maybe let know which file you found the original code for this?

Comment: Swapped the link with the github mirror, should work now.

Comment: What if we want to get classes instead of xpaths? Can you please share me the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524774/is-there-any-way-to-get-class-of-the-page-in-pyqt5-in-browser? @dcmorse

Comment: @dcmorse, Can you please give a short block of code illustrating how to use the code you posted above, Thanks :), (no-js developer)

Comment: @octopus , Just paste the above code and pass the element

window.onclick = function (e) {
    // alert(e.target)
    x = Elements.DOMPath.xPath(e.target)
    alert(x)
  }

Answer (score 6):

A similar solution is given by the function [getXPathForElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Snippets#getXPathForElement) on the MDN

> The following function allows one to pass **an element and an XML document** to find a **unique** string XPath expression leading back to that element.

Note this function works on XML documents, and **may not work on HTML documents** due to HTML's capitalization of the `nodeName` value a seen in comments...

Also this may not produce a "**unique** string XPath"; not unique in either sense :

- [**more than one XPath** could locate any given element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2661890/1175496)
- the one XPath produced by this function might identify **more than one element** (this XPath only searches by element name, so might identify multiple sibling elements with the same element name)

```js
function getXPathForElement(el, xml) {
    var xpath = '';
    var pos, tempitem2;
    
    while(el !== xml.documentElement) {     
        pos = 0;
        tempitem2 = el;
        while(tempitem2) {
            if (tempitem2.nodeType === 1 && tempitem2.nodeName === el.nodeName) { // If it is ELEMENT_NODE of the same name
                pos += 1;
            }
            tempitem2 = tempitem2.previousSibling;
        }
        
        xpath = "*[name()='"+el.nodeName+"' and namespace-uri()='"+(el.namespaceURI===null?'':el.namespaceURI)+"']["+pos+']'+'/'+xpath;

        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    xpath = '/*'+"[name()='"+xml.documentElement.nodeName+"' and namespace-uri()='"+(el.namespaceURI===null?'':el.namespaceURI)+"']"+'/'+xpath;
    xpath = xpath.replace(/\/$/, '');
    return xpath;
}
```

Also [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) might be worth a try.

Comment: Please note
`document.documentElement.nodeName` returns  **uppercase `'HTML'`** [as mentioned in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName)

But if you search for it using `/*[name()='HTML']`, **you get no results** 
`document.evaluate("/*[name()='HTML']", document.documentElement).iterateNext()` produces `null`.  

Whereas if you **use lowercase** `/*[name()='html']` you will find results. The XPath [`name()` function returns QName, which seems case sensitive!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name).

Comment: If you're dealing with HTML / Element API , consider using the [`el.localName` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/localName) instead of the `el.nodeName`, and the [`local-name()` XPath function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name) instead of the `name()` XPath function

Comment: My concerns may only apply when dealing with HTML documents, the `nodeName` property is uppercased with HTML, but ["may be cased differently for XML/XHTML documents)."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName);  later it says: "tag names of elements in an XML DOM tree are returned in the same case in which they're written in the original XML file"

Answer (score 6):

```js
function getElementXPath (element) {
  if (!element) return null

  if (element.id) {
    return `//*[@id=${element.id}]`
  } else if (element.tagName === 'BODY') {
    return '/html/body'
  } else {
    const sameTagSiblings = Array.from(element.parentNode.childNodes)
      .filter(e => e.nodeName === element.nodeName)
    const idx = sameTagSiblings.indexOf(element)

    return getElementXPath(element.parentNode) +
      '/' +
      element.tagName.toLowerCase() +
      (sameTagSiblings.length > 1 ? `[${idx + 1}]` : '')
  }
}

console.log(getElementXPath(document.querySelector('#a div')))
```

```html
<div id="a">
 <div>def</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I checked every solution provided here but none of them works with `svg` elements (code `getElementByXPath(getXPathForElement(elm)) === elm` returns `false` for `svg` or `path` elements)

So I added the [Touko's svg fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15019396/10895487) to the [trincot's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43688599/10895487) and got this code:

```js
function getXPathForElement(element) {
    const idx = (sib, name) => sib 
        ? idx(sib.previousElementSibling, name||sib.localName) + (sib.localName == name)
        : 1;
    const segs = elm => !elm || elm.nodeType !== 1 
        ? ['']
        : elm.id && document.getElementById(elm.id) === elm
            ? [`id("${elm.id}")`]
            : [...segs(elm.parentNode), elm instanceof HTMLElement
                ? `${elm.localName}[${idx(elm)}]`
                : `*[local-name() = "${elm.localName}"][${idx(elm)}]`];
    return segs(element).join('/');
}
```

The difference is it returns `*[local-name() = "tag"][n]` instead of `tag[n]` if element is not an instance of `HTMLElement` (svgs are `SVGElement` but I decided not to stick with checking only svg).

#### Example:

Before:
`.../div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/svg[1]/path[1]`

After:
`.../div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/*[local-name() = "svg"][1]/*[local-name() = "path"][1]`

Comment: So many branch conditions....haiyaa....

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the element in function `getXPathOfElement` and you will get the `Xpath`.

```
function getXPathOfElement(elt)
{
     var path = "";
     for (; elt && elt.nodeType == 1; elt = elt.parentNode)
     {
    idx = getElementIdx(elt);
    xname = elt.tagName;
    if (idx > 1) xname += "[" + idx + "]";
    path = "/" + xname + path;
     }

     return path;   
}
function getElementIdx(elt)
{
    var count = 1;
    for (var sib = elt.previousSibling; sib ; sib = sib.previousSibling)
    {
        if(sib.nodeType == 1 && sib.tagName == elt.tagName) count++
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get xPath by giving a dom element**

This function returns full xPath selector (without any id or class).
This type of selector is helpful when an site generate random id or class

```
function getXPath(element) {
    // Selector
    let selector = '';
    // Loop handler
    let foundRoot;
    // Element handler
    let currentElement = element;

    // Do action until we reach html element
    do {
        // Get element tag name 
        const tagName = currentElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
        // Get parent element
        const parentElement = currentElement.parentElement;

        // Count children
        if (parentElement.childElementCount > 1) {
            // Get children of parent element
            const parentsChildren = [...parentElement.children];
            // Count current tag 
            let tag = [];
            parentsChildren.forEach(child => {
                if (child.tagName.toLowerCase() === tagName) tag.push(child) // Append to tag
            })

            // Is only of type
            if (tag.length === 1) {
                // Append tag to selector
                selector = `/${tagName}${selector}`;
            } else {
                // Get position of current element in tag
                const position = tag.indexOf(currentElement) + 1;
                // Append tag to selector
                selector = `/${tagName}[${position}]${selector}`;
            }

        } else {
            //* Current element has no siblings
            // Append tag to selector
            selector = `/${tagName}${selector}`;
        }

        // Set parent element to current element
        currentElement = parentElement;
        // Is root  
        foundRoot = parentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'html';
        // Finish selector if found root element
        if(foundRoot) selector = `/html${selector}`;
    }
    while (foundRoot === false);

    // Return selector
    return selector;
}
```