# presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy could not find the element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test, when I use the code below:

```
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy
    (By.xpath("//div[.//span[text()='Map']]//*")));

for (WebElement e : elements) {
    System.out.println("=>" + e.getTagName() + "<=");                   
}
```

it shows all the web elements in that `<div>` tag.

Result:

```
=>span<=
=>div<=
=>div<=
=>path<=
=>path<=
=>span<=
```

As you see, some of the elements tag-name is `path` but when I use the code below it says that I could not find the element.

```
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy
    (By.xpath("//div[.//span[text()='Map']]//path")));
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code. It will help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

It not easy to find the real issue with out knowing your HTML structure.

While I think there is a issue in your xpath

Try below xpath

```
//div//span[text()='Map']//path
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

`By.xpath("//div[.//span[text()='Map']]//*` will return all the decedents of `span[text()='Map']` in the html hierarchy.

For example, this html structure will produce the same results you have

```html
<div>
  <span>Map</span>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, `<path>` is not `<span>` direct child, so `By.xpath("//div[.//span[text()='Map']]//path` is not a valid xpath.

Comment: @LoveJavaTwo I changed the html little bit, now it works. I tested it on (probably) another site so I didn't have the exact html structure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to some web elements that Selenium cannot navigate, the web element that I was trying to catch was inside a `svg` web element which is not detectable by Selenium have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943025/selenium-cannot-find-svg-element-in-xpath) this is exactly what was happening to me.