# Java: How do I get an xpath for a org.w3c.dom.Node?

Tags: java, xpath

I'm using Java 1.6.  Given a `org.w3c.dom.Node` object, how do I get a String XPath expression for where that node falls in an XML document?  It is NOT a given that this node or any of its ancestors/descendants have an `id` attribute.

Comment: This has been answered many times for JavaScript on SO. You might get some use out of looking at some of those answers. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any easy way via DOM. The problem is that there is not a single canonical way to identify a given node.

Having said that, you might find the the function getXPath from diffxml useful: http://diffxml.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/diffxml/diffxml/src/java/org/diffxml/diffxml/fmes/NodeOps.java?view=markup

It will return an XPath of the form /node()[4]/node()[2] etc.

UPDATE: As diffxml is GPL licensed and getXPath takes a bit of extracting, I released it as XPathGen on github: https://github.com/amouat/XPathGen under an Apache licence.

Comment: There might not be a *canonical* way to represent a node, but you can always do it accurately by position.

Comment: I use code just like this for debugging purposes.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your node and an empty string to a recursive method such as this one:

```
static void xpm(Node node, String xpath){
    if (node.getParentNode()==null){
        System.out.println(xpath);
        return;
    }

    xpath = "/"+node.getNodeName()+xpath;
    node = node.getParentNode();
    xpm(node, xpath);
}
```