# Is it possible to send a DOM reference to another browser thru a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to be able to send some element that I selected with JQuery to another browser which opened the same page. Like if focus a textfield, the selection to happen on the second browser too. With a server, that's possible, but is there a way to serialize or somehow transfer the element reference (not id, cause not every element has an id)

Comment: Generate an xpath reference to the element.

Comment: For more on implementing @epascarello's comment, see [Javascript get XPath of a node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node)

Answer (score 0):

Not so much transfering, but you can "reveal" your values to a specific browser.  Try setting up a conditional statement for browser **feature detection**, within a ajax request on success() or on done(), to then display your DOM reference for a specific browser.  Hope this helps.