# Is it possible to get the XPATH query string from XPathExpression?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, javax.xml

An XPath query is compiled into an XPathExpression, which can then be evaluted on  document. Suppose if i have hold of only all the compiled expressions, is it possible to know what are the respective xpath queries for them ?

Comment: refer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119818/create-xpath-expression-programmatically

Comment: refer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834109/chrome-extension-programmatically-inspect-element-and-copy-xpath-or-copy-css

Answer (score 0):

No, the JAXP XPathExpression class does not offer this capability. (Some implementations of this interface might do so, but that's a different question.)