# How can i capture the xpath of an element using UFT?

Tags: xpath, hp-uft

I want to capture the xpath of an element in IE11 through UFT.Is it possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269352/asking-about-the-existence-of-a-particular-technique-without-being-too-broad/269359#269359

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no **the** XPath of an element, each element may have multiple XPaths (this is why UFT doesn't supply a default value for the XPath).

You can look for a JavaScript implementation (like the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178132/3848)) and then use `Page.RunScript` to get an XPath for your selected element.

The problem is to pass the element to the JavaScript, one way you can use is via IE's [`sourceIndex'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534635.aspx).

something like this (untested code follows).

```
Browser("B").Page("P").RunScriptFromFile("C:\defineGetXPath.js")
SrcIndex = Browser("B").Page("P").WebElement("E").GetROProperty("source_index")
XPath =Browser("B").Page("P").RunScript( "getXPath(document.all[" & SrcIndex & "])" )
```

Comment: Old, but wrong, no? Should be .GetROProperty("attribute/source_index")

Comment: @TheBlastOne no, `source_index` is an _identification property_ that UFT supports for all browsers (not only IE) although I'm not sure how official this support is... using `attribute/` is for getting native properties of the DOM element which UFT doesn't specifically support.