# How to override the generated div class from ui- include

Tags: css

I am Trying to remove scroll bar from div generated from ui-include tag but unsuccessful

I can only test and change in chrome inspect and nothing else I can do about it It is generating a div with class ui- layout- unit-content  which has scroll bar

How can I modify this default behaviour only for one page or one include only

Thanks

Comment: You should probably include a jsf tag if that's what you're using, also you should add minimal reproducible example, even if it's just the generated html. Other than that you can usually solve that type of problem by using `overflow: hidden` in css, but it's better if you discover what is causing the overflow and remove that instead

Comment: in style tag of page i added overflow: hidden; and override 2 classes that were generated in div of ui -include, now its working

Comment: Glad I could help, but if you can it would be a better pratice if you could find the element causing the overflow and fix it. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458477/find-element-that-is-causing-the-showing-of-horizontal-scrollbar-in-google-chrom) has useful answers to help identifying it, and modern web browsers come with a lot of tools in the inspector to also help.