# Show scroll only when it needs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

```css
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 5px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: var(--back-color);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: var(--main-color);
      width: 5px;
    }
```

Here is how I specified the scroll properties.

What needs to change to display scroll only if it needs? Right now it always show scroll.

Comment: Check for `overflow: scroll`, which causes the scroll bar to become visible at all times.  Also, just to make sure that the scroll bar appears only when it shouldn't, try using one of the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31458477/).

Comment: `overflow: auto` is correct. with `scroll` it will always be there, with `auto` only when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because your element does have a length that exceeds the screen or you have `overflow:scroll` in your CSS.

`overflow:scroll` keeps the scrollbars always appear, while `overflow:auto` makes the scrollbars appear only when needed. Check this out:

```css
.parent {overflow:scroll}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

And this:

```css
.parent {overflow:auto}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Lorem ipsum
</div>
```