# Get the selector string from DOM element with native Javascript

Tags: javascript

Usually, we use `querySelectorAll('html:eq(0) > body:eq(0) > div.row:eq(0) > div.span4:eq(2) > p.p3:eq(2)')` to get the DOM ELEMENT.

If I want to use the ELEMENT `<p class="p3">target</p>` with native javascript to get the selector string, what should I do?

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <p class="p1">p1_1<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p1">p1_2<p>
        <p class="p1">p1_3<p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="span4">
        <p class="p2">p2_1<p>
        <p class="p2">p2_2<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p2">p2_3<p>
    </div>
    <p>stranger</p>
    <div class="span4">
        <p class="p3">p3_1<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p3">p3_2<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p3">target<p>
    </div>
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <p class="p3">p1<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p3">p2<p>
        <p class="p3">p3<p>
    </div>
<div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <p>stranger</p>
<div>
```

Thses are what I think:

1. Taking advantage of those attributes of the element `<p class="p3">target</p>`, I found these are useful:

   - attributes
   - nextElementSibling
   - previousElementSibling
   - parentElement
2. Attribute => *attributes*: I can use it generate the string like `div.className#idName`, this is not hard to do.
3. Attribute =>  *nextElementSibling, previousElementSibling*: I can use it generate the string like `:eq(0)`.

*What I met as a **problem** is the Step3, because if there are BR between two DIV, then this two ElementSibling will return BR, it means the BR is treated as a brother of this two div who has the same class, but that is not i want.*

So I tried to consider use Step3.1:

3.1. Attribute => parentElement: Use element's parent to get the eq, who it is ? 0, 1, 2.....

***But*** I find i cannot specify targeting element is which one, because he has so many same brothers have the same tagName, and className....

I would like to know if you guys have any good ideas?

Comment: :eq() is not a CSS selector. Also, any arbitrary element is uniquely reachable by at least one selector.

Comment: Are you trying to select whichever element has the content "target" in it? It's a little unclear what exactly your goal is.

Comment: @TylerH sorry, the element which content is "target", is just an example here, i want to create a function in the end, for any element

Comment: @BoltClock Thank your for your reply, i know there are some arbitrary elements, it is just an example, off course, in the end, this function is used for the uniq element

Comment: @LeylaLee So you want to select all elements that are the last child of their parent? Or specifically the last `<p>` of each group of `<p>` elements?

Comment: @LeylaLee Oh, you want to select the element that has unique content?

Comment: @TylerH: The OP wants to generate a selector string for an arbitrary element. Kind of like the "Copy Unique Selector" option in the DOM inspector.

Comment: @TylerH I want to generate a selector string for an arbitrary element.

Comment: @BoltClock, thank your for your replay, you got it!

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to find the element based on the html, in this case "target", you can do this:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var targetElm;
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   if (elms[i].innerHTML === 'target') {
       targetElm = elms[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: No, the OP has an element and is trying to build a selector string for it.

Comment: @BoltClock It doesn't seem like she's defined a case that can be reduced to a unique selector.  If it is unique content she is searching for, the above answer is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, mac. But if there are some other elements whose innerHTML is also 'taget'? But the other elements is not the same with the input of function....

Comment: @LeylaLee you can apply a sub selection based on the document.querySelectorAll.  I'm not sure I'm understanding your use case well enough to provide a selector here.  Can you elaborate what you mean by "the other elements is not the same with the input of the function"?

Comment: @mac sorry for my bad english T.T , ok for `example <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <p class="p1">p1_1<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p1">p1_2<p>
        <p class="p1">p1_3<p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="span4">
        <p class="p2">p2_1<p>
        <p class="p2">p2_2<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p3">target<p>
    </div>
    <p>stranger</p>
    <div class="span4">
        <p class="p3">p3_1<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p3">p3_2<p>
        <br>
        <p class="p3">target<p>
    </div>
<div>`

Comment: @mac omg, the bad formate, sorry... What i got for the input of the function is the first target, but if we follow your function, it will also generate selector string for the second element which also have innerHTML 'target'

Comment: The OP is not interested in the fact that the element's content is "target". She has a reference to this element, and is looking for a way to build a selector string that is guaranteed to match this element and only this element in this DOM. Every element has at least one such selector, and in a naïve solution the majority of these will rely on liberal use of :nth-child().

Comment: @BoltClock thank you for adding clarification.  @Lelya if you already have a reference to the element, why not apply a unique attribute instead?  `elm.setAttribute('data-id', Date.now());` or something similar.

Comment: I think you are looking for the Xpath, but I'm not sure there is native functionality to generate this for you.  However you can see this answer for a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node