# Get unique identification number from browser using only javascript in a raw html file?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way to get a unique identification number from a browser without using methods such as generating a unique number and storing it in cookies or localstorage and also without using a server side language?

Answer (score 0):

Since generating GUID is not an option, i'd suggest using [XPATH](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). Which I originally use for frontend automation testing, can also be used in my opinion for your case. See `getPathTo()` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node) answer for one possible approach.

Comment: what does xpath/getPathInfo() do in this case?