# Web scraping buttons and fields with same type name

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a code for web scraping. It operates pretty well but after some operations I can't figure how to proceed as there is no unique parameters to connect VBA commands to.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub ChechAutomate()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, url As String, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data")

    url = "https://infra.com"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 url

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document

        If .querySelectorAll("#login-bis-id-btn").Length > 0 Then

            .querySelector("[name=userName]").Value = "username"
            .querySelector("[name=password]").Value = "password"
            .querySelector("[type=submit]").Click

        Else

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

            .querySelector("[id=companySearchKeyData]").Value = ws.Range("T24").Value
            .querySelector("[type=submit]").Click

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

            .querySelector("[name=creditType] [value='17']").Selected = True

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

            .querySelector("[id=legalForms] [value='EN']").Selected = True

        End If

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

1) After upper code is ready I need to click this button:

[image]

I have tried `.querySelector("[name=#]").Click`. Text "New decision" is changing within the language of the page. Also there are other `type="button"` buttons.

2) After (1) has been done, I need to input value to this field:

[image]

I have tried to use `.querySelector("[name=questions[0].answer]").Value = "1000"`
it gives an error.

3) After (1) and (2) I need to click a button:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _Text "New decision" is changing within the language of the page_  ? Also, please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html not post images so we can use for testing,

Comment: If I choose another language on a web page, for example German then "New decision" text will be "Neue Entscheidung". Of course one option is list all the possible variants (there will be 3) but I was wondering if there is some common solution to click it in every language version. I would be glad to share source code to make it easier but there is too much private information.

Comment: But sharing as images is not that helpful I'm afraid. Can you obfuscate the private info? I am about to post a short term answer we can work on. Also, do this language change other parts of the problem? For example, the attribute values for the last button (part 3 of your question)?

Comment: I understand that image is not so much help... `value="Order"` is changing according to language settings

Comment: The same solutions as per your problem  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveat:**

We really need to see more html. Without seeing the entire html (obfuscate private info) with problems like 1 and 3 I can only give general approaches to consider.

---

**Problem 1)**

For now, you have three other options at least:

1) grab the collection/nodelist and index in to get correct button/loop all items
checking for unique innerText/attribute if available

```
Set col = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")  'collection. For Each over
Set nodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll("input") 'nodelist. For i = 0 to nodeList.Length -1
```

Indexing:

```
col(0)  'example index
nodeList.item(0)  'example index
```

2) Find a relationship between this element and another that captures this element. Or some combination of attributes to identify. See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632361/6241235) for some further detail.

For example, perhaps adding parent div class

```
ie.document.querySelector("div.content [type=button]")
```

3) Pass a list with Or syntax of the language variants

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='New decision'], [value='Neue Entscheidung'],[value='Other language variant']")
```

---

**Problem 2)**

You need to use single quotes inside of double quotes

```
ie.document.querySelector("[name='questions[0].answer']").value = 1000
```

---

**Problem 3)**

As per problem 1.

---

**Footnotes:**

Remember `querySelector` returns first match for pattern, `querySelectorAll` returns all matches.

Comment: I figured out how to dive deep starting from div from your answer. Also your solution with double quotes helped. Thank you again master!