# How can I get the xpath value of clicked element in page? [JS]

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I'm working in automatic test (extension chrome), backend it's done, and I only need a clue or know which is the way to do this, get the xpath of an element when the user clicks it (in js).

Thanks,

Comment: I would say it's related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node