# Google Chrome: Is it possible to copy XPath dynamically (in code)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, domxpath

In google chrome, you can get the xpath of an element via  if you right click on an element -> copy xpath:

[Here is how GIF](https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--f3GI8Xwk--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_66%2Cw_880/https://thepracticaldev.s3.amazonaws.com/i/cv9yhr3hyhkdofksmcey.gif)

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to dynamically access an xpath generated by Chrome using some Chrome Api (?) / Functions. I want to be able to copy the xpath in code?

**Any ideas please?**

***Or** if you know a better way to locate a dom element (i.e. a reference that can be persisted so I can locate it 'later' e.g. on another server)?*

Comment: Why? Computer-generated XPath is next to useless.

Comment: Please explain? I'm wondering if there is a chrome api function where you can pass in dom element (id?) and returns the xpath. Similar to what a user can do on chrome GUI - hope that makes sense? I need a way to locate a dom element and persist it (as a reference - even though i know it can be changed /  is fragile..)

Comment: Please let me know if you know a better way to locate a dom element (i.e. a reference that can be persisted so I can locate it 'later' e.g. on another server)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node see answer number 2

Comment: I have seen this answer, been testing this function - unfortunately it breaks on edge cases - e.g. returns empty class name sometimes i.e. /div[@class=""] - Really hard to do this  reliably!

Comment: I know what you mean, but the *result* of automatic XPath generation is useless. XPath is meant to be written by hand. Automatically generated XPath is too complicated and much too specific, and even small changes in the DOM structure, like they happen all the time in today's dynamic pages, will cause those XPaths to break. In other words, they are not stable enough to be useful.

Comment: Is there a better alternative to xpath - perhaps?

Comment: @Tomalak is right:  XPath is not the problem.  Your expectation that there is a single answer to the question of how to locate an unidentified node in a document is the problem.  Without specifying a fixed framework or a fixed set of invariants, your question is under-constrained and autogenerated XPath's have to be over-constrained.