# Creating a constant time data structure for DOM element references

Tags: javascript

[Relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881768/what-is-the-unique-identifier-for-a-dom-element-node).

I understand I can build an array of references to elements/nodes. I realize also that I could use the neat trick of treating an array like a heap (index `2n` and `2n+1` for children) to build a (potentially wasteful) binary search tree using it.

But all that's still not enough for the premature optimizer in me. Besides, implementing a BST is going to be bug prone.

Here's my question. Can I somehow use an element reference as index into javascript's hashes (which are objects, or vice versa?). If not, can I conjure up a unique string from an element reference, which I can then use as my hash key? If not, how the hell does jQuery do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A fast lookup from a DOM node to your own data structure? If so, you can always attach custom properties to node objects.

Comment: @AtesGoral, You are correct that is what i am trying to achieve. I was not aware of the difference between attributes and properties. Will editing properties on a given node persist over the life of that node (as it exists in the document)?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but the properties for a particular DOM node _should_ persist during the life time of that node. I don't know if there are special cases on certain browsers that cause a new JS object to be assigned to an existing DOM node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to just use your own attribute on the DOM object:

```
var element = document.getElementById("test");
element.myData = "whatever";
```

Here's the general idea behind how jQuery's `.data()` function works that you could use in your own plain javascript.  It uses one custom attribute on the object and then stores everything else in a data structure indexed by the value of that custom attribute.

```
var idCntr = 0;   // global cntr

var data = {};
var element = document.getElementById("test");
var id = element.uniqueID;
if (!id) {
    id = idCntr++ + "";
    element.uniqueID = id;
}
data[id] = "whatever";


// then some time later, you can do this
var element = document.getElementById("test");
console.log(data[element.uniqueID]);   // whatever
```

It is a bit more involved to store multiple attributes for a given object in the data object, but this is the general idea.

And, if you can use jQuery, it's trivial:

```
$("#test").data("myData", "whatever");  // sets the data

console.log($("#test").data("myData"));   // retrieves the data
```

If you want to really see how jQuery's `.data()` works, you can step through the first call to set data and then retrieve it when using the unminified jQuery.  It's easy to see what it does.